# MATLAB subtract every row of matrix by a given vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, subtraction

Let

```
M = | 1 2 3 |
    | 4 5 6 |
    | 7 8 9 |
```

and

```
V = | 1 1 1 |
```

I want to subtract V from every row of M so that M should look like

```
M = | 0 1 2 |
    | 3 4 5 |
    | 6 7 8 |
```

How can I do that without using a *for*, is there any straightforward command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>> M = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
>> V = [1 1 1];
>> MV = M-repmat(V,size(M,1),1)

MV =

     0     1     2
     3     4     5
     6     7     8
```

The call to repmat repeats the vector V by the number of rows in M.

User [beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377097/beaker) pointed out that an even simpler (though a bit obscure) syntax works in recent versions of MATLAB.  If you subtract a vector from a matrix, MATLAB will extend the vector to match the size of the matrix as long as one dimension of vector matches the matrix dimensions.  See [Compatible Array Sizes for Basic Operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html).

```
>> M-V

ans =

     0     1     2
     3     4     5
     6     7     8
```

Of course, if you know that V will contain all 1s, the solution is even simpler:

```
>> MV = M-1

MV =

     0     1     2
     3     4     5
     6     7     8
```

Comment: For current versions of MATLAB, `M-V` would work, too.

Comment: Thanks, @beaker.  I edited the response to include your input.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use *bsxfun*.

```
M = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9] ;
V = [1 1 1] ;
iwant = bsxfun(@minus,M,V)
```